# Xcode Validating Archive Stuck

Tags: xcode

I am trying to submit my first app to App Store using Xcode (beta version). I followed the instruction from the following link from Apple.

[App Distribution Guide from Apple](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/IDEs/Conceptual/AppDistributionGuide/TestingYouriOSApp/TestingYouriOSApp.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40012582-CH8-SW1)

I have created Archive and clicked "Validate". I have been waiting for 20 mins but still no response. I googled this but couldn't find anything quite relevant.

Is this a common problem? Sorry I don't have enough reputation to put up the screenshot. It is showing me "Preparing Archive" with an indicator spinning (so I thought it was doing something) but no response after 20 mins still.

Comment: Nothing wrong here, it seems your network connection is too slow.

Comment: well..i got a fairly fast connection but..

Comment: Try using `Application Loader` to distribute your app. Or sometimes patience helps us a lot :)

Comment: Hi @Zubair thanks your comments. I tried doing it with Xcode and now gave up. Downloaded Application Loader and trying to submit..

Comment: thanks very much!! fingers crossed..